# Can we please "lock" a post during edit

Tags: feature-request

This has happened many times, I see a post which is fairly big and un-readable. No problem, the OP is not English and I can help. To get half way through when I see a notification telling me an update has been made!

When some one edit's a post, can it be locked to prevent others from editing the post at the same time please?

**EDIT**

As per the post [Lock a post for editing, or at least display a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/lock-a-post-for-editing-or-at-least-display-a-warning) I don't think a warning is acceptable personally because it allows people to ignore it!

Comment: Yes! Please! :D

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - Yeah, sorry, it just happened to us (sorry for over writing you) but this is not the first time it has happened sadly.

Comment: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/lock-a-post-for-editing-or-at-least-display-a-warning](Lock a post for editing, or at least display a warning)

Comment: Yeah, happens all the time :(

Comment: The problem about actually *locking* a post is, when will it be unlocked?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I would stick on a fixed time limit (or a notification when they leave the page the lock will be released)

Comment: There's a reason Git and Mercurial don't do this, and likewise, there's a reason the Stack Exchange websites don't.  I believe as-is a warning will be displayed if you try to submit an edit to a post that was edited *after* you started your edits.